# Alternative for document.querySelector in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've red many articles about using `useRef` in react js. According to [react js documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), `Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.`. 
From all of documentation, i understood that, if you want to access a dom element, you have to add the ref like this: 

`<div ref={myRef}`, and after that easy to access it.
I understood that `useRef` is used when we have access to the html markup.

**Question**: How to access a css selector (`.class, #id`), when my html is generated by a library, like 
AntD or something else?

How to access this selector if i can't use `document.querySelector` according to react documentation? EX:

```css
 document.querySelector('my selector').style.color = 'yellow';
```

Which is the alternative for the last code snippet in react js?

**NOTE**: I don't want to change the styles with css, but i need to change it according to some js logic.

Comment: You can use `document.querySelector`, but it's not as reliable. React is based on the idea that each component exists entirely as `state` and `props`, which can then be rendered as HTML at any point, and re-rendered when either changes. The best way to approach directly changing the rendered HTML depends on which library you want to use, and what HTML it generates.

Answer (score 7):

You *can* use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` in situations where the DOM structure you're accessing is generated outside of React. That's absolutely fine when you have no other choice.

You'd probably use them on the outermost element of your component or the element in which you're having the non-React library do its thing (which you'd get via a ref), rather than on `document`, so that they're working just within your component's part of the DOM rather than the entire document.

Here's an example:

```js
"use strict";
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;

// A stand-in for your non-React library
function nonReactLibraryFunction(element, value) {
    element.innerHTML =
        `<div>
            This is content from the non-React lib, value =
            <span class="value">${value}</span>
        </div>`;
}

// A stand-in for your component
const Example = ({value}) => {
    // The ref for the wrapper around the lib's stuff
    const fooRef = useRef(null);

    // When `value` changes, have the library do something (this
    // is just an example)
    useEffect(() => {
        // Valid target?
        if (fooRef.current) {
            // Yes, let the lib do its thing
            nonReactLibraryFunction(fooRef.current, value);

            // Find the element we want to change and change it
            const color = value % 2 === 0 ? "blue" : "red";
            fooRef.current.querySelector(".value").style.color = color;
        }
    }, [value]);

    return (
        <div>
            This is my component, value = {value}.
            <div ref={fooRef} />
        </div>
    );
};

// A wrapper app that just counts upward
const App = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => setValue(v => v + 1), 800);
    }, [value]);

    return <Example value={value} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: could you take  a look please, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345237/save-data-in-a-special-order-when-click-on-button . It will be very helpful

Answer (score 3):

If you use external libraries that generate their own markup. Nothing bad to use `element.querySelector`

You can do something like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   const element = document.querySelector(selector);
}, []);
```

But if you use a library from React's ecosystem like Antd or material-ui, they probably have an API with refs. It can be called like `innerRef`, `nestedRef` or just `ref`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous anwsers: if this generated html is generated inside your component you can use querySelector on `useRef.current` to search for element only inside component ;)

```
const Component = () => {
  const componentRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const elFromLibraryComponent = componentRef.current.querySelector('my selector');

    if (elFromLibraryComponent) {
       ...do something...
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div ref={componentRef}>
      <ComponentFromLibrary />
    </div>
  )
}
```

There are even libraries that allows to pass ref as prop to components so it is also usefull

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple external resources to generate markup. Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
const element = window.parent.document.querySelector(selector);
},[]);
```

Answer (score -2):

We can also manipulate HTML Dom element by tags,id,class with the help of document.getElementsByTag('TagName').Document.getElementById('IdName'),Document.getElementsByClass('ClassName').